# Charles proxy - установлено подключение без доступа к сети Интернет при попытке подключения мобильного устройства

Tags: android, ubuntu, proxy, сниффер, charles

ОС Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Charles Proxy установила для сниффинга HTTP-трафика мобильного приложения.
Настройки на компьютере с установленным Charles:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки сети на мобильном устройстве:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь открыть HTTP-сайты, не открываются. Интернет-соединения нет. В Charles трафик мобильного устройства не виден. Окошко с предложением разрешить подключение устройства тоже не всплывает. Появляется лишь нечто - JavaEmbeddedFrame, которое не открывается при клике.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как подружить Charles и мобильное устройство.

Comment: Последний скрин - не виден.

Comment: @donRumata Этот? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeHwM.png

Comment: Да. 300+х200+ пикселей - мелковато.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная проблема. Поскольку все это делала для работы, то мешал рабочий ВПН на ноутбуке. После отключения ВПН и подключения `Charles` уже через свободный инет с телефоном моментально сконнектился.

Дальше была проблема со скачиванием сертификата. При переходе на `chls.pro/ssl` писал ошибку про `external proxy`. Осенило, что в настройках `Charles` был указан `External Proxy` (опять же для работы). После отключения `External Proxy` сертификат скачался без проблем.